# How to horizontally shift a calligraphic letter?

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment

I have tried to create a newcommand to shift the calligraphic M `\mathcal{M}` some points to the left with several things along these lines:

```
\newcommand{\smathcal}[1]{\hspace{-5pt}\mathcal}
```

However, all I try either delivers an error or does not do what I expect. **Could anybody please help me get the right command to achieve what I need?**

See a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\smathcal}[1]{\hspace*{-5pt}\mathcal}
\begin{document}
$\smathcal{M}$
\end{document}
```

Thank you all in advance very much for your time

Comment: Try using `\hspace*{}` instead of `\hspace{}`.  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I already added a MWE (see my original answer). I also tried the solution you suggested, which unfortunately did not work.

Comment: I have it in my head that one should use `\kern` for this sort of thing, but I don't actually remember why.

Comment: Why `-5pt`? You probably are doing some specific logo or something similar and you want it to adapt to the surrounding conditions, so a *relative* unit such as `em` or `mu` should be used.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I am basically typsetting something of the form `\nu_{\mathcal{M}}^{S}` and the caligraphic M is too far away from the `\nu` (at least, with the Fourier font). Hence, I wanted a new caligraphic M shifted to the left such that it is closer to `\nu`. I will use `\kern`, `em` or `mu` if that's what you advise me to do.

Comment: not explicitly explained in the answer, but syntax of command is corected ... when you use `[1]` to indicate an argument, you have to either have `#1` in the expansion, or expect that the next token read after the command will vanish from the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\hspace*{}` instead of `\hspace{}`, which is ignored at the start of a line, does the trick:

[image]

### Notes:

- I added the `\usepackage{showframe}` so that one can see the effect.
- You were also missing the `#1` in the `\newcommand`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\smathcal}[1]{\hspace*{-5pt}\mathcal{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\mathcal{M}$

\noindent
$\smathcal{M}$

\end{document}
```